# Emacs regular expression: Backreference contains nothing

Tags: emacs, regex, find-and-replace

Recently I switched from Sublime to Emacs with Evil mode. After configuring I'm trying to use it productively but I can't find a way to use the backreference in Emacs. In the manual it says I have to use \#, so I'm using \1 but it's always empty (also tried 0 but Emacs doesn't accept it).

For example I would like to add brackets to the word Lorem:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

So after entering `<C-M-%>`, `Lorem`, `<RET>`, `(\1)`, `<RET>`, `<y>` I'm getting this:

```
() ipsum dolor sit amet
```

In Sublime I would use `Lorem` as find and `($0)` as replace to get this:

```
(Lorem) ipsum dolor sit amet
```

I also tried **visual-replace-steroids** but it has the same behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use in the replacement `(\&)` instead of `(\1)`. `\1` is for the 1st `\(...\)` group from the regexp.

This is described in the help obtainable with M-x describe-key C-M-%:

> In `TO-STRING`, `\&` stands for whatever matched the whole of `REGEXP`,
>   and `\N` (where N is a digit) stands for whatever matched
>   the Nth `\(...\)` (1-based) in REGEXP.  The `\(...\)` groups are
>   counted from 1.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :) I guess I interpreted backreference wrong.